# Buy X amount of products for a reduced price

Tags: magento, magento2

How would I go about a rule which sets something along the lines of:

```
--------------------------
| Amount in Cart | Price |
--------------------------
|       1        | 1,99  |
|       3        | 1,50  |
|       5        | 1,20  |
--------------------------
```

I can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can enter product prices under `Catalog > Manage Products > Price Section`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is called tier prices in Magento.
Quoting Magento Doc :

> Tier pricing lets you offer a quantity discount from the catalog list and product detail pages. The discount can be applied to a specific store view or customer group.

Full description of this feature here : http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-price-tier.html